# CLion Plugin: Register file extension with existing language

Tags: intellij-plugin, clion

I'm developing a plugin for CLion to add new extensions to be recognized as C++ source. I've looked in StdLanguage but C++ is not there even though both CLion and IDEA have built-in support for C++ syntax.

How do I register the extensions with C++? I don't want to add any new features or define a new language, just register these extensions as C++ source.

I know it's possible to do it via the GUI but this is for a plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the file type for C++ files, use `FileTypeManager.getFileTypeByExtension("cpp")`. Once you have that, you can call `FileTypeManager.associateExtension()` to associate an additional extension with it.

Comment: Thanks. That did it. What I had to do though was FileTypeManager.getInstance()